# Modifying specific column headers in Excel Power Query

Tags: powerquery

I have an Excel table that, in addition to providing a number of other filters/presentations, contains a handful of **variable** headers that I want to convert into consistent column names so that the rest of the M code can be straightforward.

One set of headers might look like this

| AAA | BBB | CCC | A Tool One - Site1 | Another Tool - Site1 | Third and Final Tool - Site1 | DDD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

A second set of headers might look like this

| AAA | BBB | CCC | A Tool One - SecondSite | Another Tool - SecondSite | Third and Final Tool - SecondSite | DDD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

A third set of headers might look like this

| AAA | BBB | CCC | A Tool One - NoThreeLocale | Third and Final Tool - NoThreeLocale | DDD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

All relevant column headers will be in the format of:

- **tool name**
- *SpaceHyphenSpace* ( - )
- **site info**
  *Note that each **tool name** is consistent between sites, but each tool/column is distinct in both character length and number of words*

I would like to make all of them consistent, junking everything after and including the *SpaceHyphenSpace* leaving me with the following (all headers trimmed):

| AAA | BBB | CCC | A Tool One | Another Tool | Third and Final Tool | DDD |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |

As shown in the third example, it is possible that all sites will not have all tools present, and I'd like to only have headers for columns which will have data.

I've tried several iterations but cannot get past creating the new column names. I think that once I do, I have the correct code that will do the renaming:

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(),
    UserExport = Source{[Name="UserExport"]}[Content],
    #"Removed Blank Rows" = Table.SelectRows(UserExport, each not List.IsEmpty(List.RemoveMatchingItems(Record.FieldValues(_), {"", null}))),
    #"Promoted Headers" = Table.PromoteHeaders(#"Removed Blank Rows", [PromoteAllScalars=true]),

    OldNames = List.Select( Table.ColumnNames(#"Promoted Headers"), each (Text.Contains(_, "Tool")) ),
    NewNames = Table.FromList({OldNames},Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("-") ),
    Renamed = List.Zip({OldNames,NewNames}),
    Custom = Table.RenameColumns(Navigation,Renamed),
)
in
    #"Added Custom1"
```

For Site1, **OldNames** gives me
||List|
|---|---|
|1|A Tool One - Site1|
|2|Another Tool - Site1|
|3|Third and Final Tool - Site1|

But **NewNames** throws the following error

```
Expression.Error: We cannot convert a value of type List to type Text.
Details:
    Value=[List]
    Type=[Type]
```

I've tried a dozen other snippets to get **NewNames** to be in the same format as OldNames, but I get similar errors that complain about format mismatches every time, regardless if I'm converting to values, lists, or tables. The closest I've come (with a wholly different set of M code for NewNames) left me with
|OldNames|NewNames|
|---|---|
|A Tool One - Site1|List|
|Another Tool - Site1|List|
|Third and Final Tool - Site1|List|

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `NewNames`is not defined in your query. Perhaps you have it declared elsewere.

Comment: You use the `Last seen in` string in the query. The question doesn't mention it.

Comment: Both are now fixed. Thank you.

Additionally, the tables are showing up correctly in the preview, but not in the actual display :(

Comment: And now the tables are showing up properly, thanks to adding blank lines before them... TIL! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have a little query which seems to do the job:

```ml
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="YourTable"]}[Content],
    Renamed = Table.RenameColumns(Source,
                        List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source),
                                       each {_,let p = Text.PositionOf(_,"-")
                                               in 
                                                  if p=-1 
                                               then _ 
                                                  else Text.Trim(Text.Start(_,p))}))
in
    Renamed
```

To make the query simpler, I rename all the columns... and sometimes, the new name is equal to the old one.

Note: this version will strip "-" alone and also "    -", with extra hyphens.

Comment: Thank you @Frédéric LOYER, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

You could try

```
Rename= Table.RenameColumns( #"PriorStepGoesNameHere", List.Zip( { Table.ColumnNames( Source ),List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each Text.Split(_," -"){0})}))
```

replace Table.ColumnNames(Source) with some other list of column names if you plan to apply this to some subset, like perhaps OldNames

Comment: This looks like it would also work, but my eye was drawn first to Frédéric's non-obfuscated version. Thank you, though!

Comment: I didn't realize I was obfuscating, but whatever is best for you!